# Strange Typescript build error with angular2 and webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have integrated webpack in my existing working angular2 app starting with the webpack starter kit. But now if I run the build with

```
npm run build:dev
```

I recive this and many other similar errors:

```
ERROR in [default] C\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts:102:5
    Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
```

What I have duplicated? Is it why I have included this typings file:

```
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the typings. It looks like `@types` are already being used. Maybe that is the conflict. Not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by removing typings files and folders.

Comment: How did you compiled `ts` files after you deleted `typings` folder ?

Anything else added in  `package.json` or `typings.json`

If i remove typings folder i'm getting error in webpack process

Comment: I removed also the typings.json file